# Bougainvillea flowering crisis

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, bougainvillea

My bougainvillea plant hardly flowers and only at the tips. It has one very long vertically growing stem(if I may call it so).

[image]

Is this an example of apical dominance. If so how is it to be corrected? Do I have to cut the long step?

Days are long and it is monsoon in India.
It receives 3 hours of direct sunshine in the morning, and ample ventilation continuously.

It is watered with nearly 500 cc every afternoon.

I have already employed means like trimming, pruning etc. with no avail.

Do I have to cut the stem?

Comment: I think you need more sun to get blooms.

Comment: @blacksmith37 But do I have to cut that long branch?

Comment: I would trim it because it is out of proportion.